# How to access outlook address book using outlook rest api

Tags: php, azure, rest, oauth-2.0, outlook

I would like to access the global address book of an organization through outlook rest api

I was  able to implement the Single Sign-on part using OAUTH2 but I'm unable to understand how to access the contacts object

I have gone through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/contacts-rest-operations) 
and many other examples but unable to understand how to implement them in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want to use the rest api to access the outlook contacts, at the moment, Microsoft suggests customers use the [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph)

Secondly, regarding how to get outlook conatcts with php application, you need to use [oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) to add Azure AD authentication and get Azure AD access token then call the api to get contacts with the access token. For example, please refer to the following steps to know how to implement it in php web application

1. [Register Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=2)
2. Configure app permissions you need for your application
   [image]
   [image]
3. Implement Azure AD authentication with the SDK `oauth2-client`
   a. Create a `.env` file

   ```
   OAUTH_APP_ID=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
   OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD=YOUR_APP_PASSWORD_HERE
   OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI=<your redirect url>
   OAUTH_SCOPES='openid profile offline_access' + <your need outlook permissions>
   OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
   OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/token
   ```

   b. Get access token

   ````
     <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class AuthController extends Controller
   {
   public function signin()
   {
     // Initialize the OAuth client
     $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
       'clientId'                => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
       'clientSecret'            => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
       'redirectUri'             => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
       'urlAuthorize'            => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
       'urlAccessToken'          => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
       'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
       'scopes'                  => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
     ]);

     $authUrl = $oauthClient->getAuthorizationUrl();

     // Save client state so we can validate in callback
     session(['oauthState' => $oauthClient->getState()]);

     // Redirect to AAD signin page
     return redirect()->away($authUrl);
   }

   public function callback(Request $request)
   {
     // Validate state
     $expectedState = session('oauthState');
     $request->session()->forget('oauthState');
     $providedState = $request->query('state');

     if (!isset($expectedState)) {
       // If there is no expected state in the session,
       // do nothing and redirect to the home page.
       return redirect('/');
     }

     if (!isset($providedState) || $expectedState != $providedState) {
       return redirect('/')
         ->with('error', 'Invalid auth state')
         ->with('errorDetail', 'The provided auth state did not match the expected value');
     }

     // Authorization code should be in the "code" query param
     $authCode = $request->query('code');
     if (isset($authCode)) {
       // Initialize the OAuth client
       $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
         'clientId'                => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
         'clientSecret'            => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
         'redirectUri'             => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
         'urlAuthorize'            => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
         'urlAccessToken'          => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
         'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
         'scopes'                  => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
       ]);

       try {
         // Make the token request
         $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
           'code' => $authCode
         ]);


          return redirect()->route('contacts');
       }
       catch (League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
         return redirect('/')
           ->with('error', 'Error requesting access token')
           ->with('errorDetail', $e->getMessage());
       }
     }

     return redirect('/')
       ->with('error', $request->query('error'))
       ->with('errorDetail', $request->query('error_description'));
   }
   }
       ```
   ````
4. Use the access token With [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#install-the-microsoft-graph-php-sdk). For more details, please refer to the [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
public function mail()
{
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }

  $tokenCache = new \App\TokenStore\TokenCache;

  $graph = new Graph();
  $graph->setAccessToken($tokenCache->getAccessToken());

  $contacts = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me/contacts/{Id}')
                ->setReturnType(Model\Contact::class)
                ->execute();


}
```

Regarding the details of how to implement it, please refer to the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial)

Besides, if you want to call the outlook rest api with php, please refer to the [document](https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial/tree/outlook-api). But please note that you need to change the app permissions.

[image]